# Atualizar dados com Alerta sonoro

Tags: php, javascript

Neste script a baixo ele fica atualizando a div e mostrando um contador

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Oque eu queria é que havendo alguma alteração no numero, tocar um Som "Um Alarme" só que eu não tenho conhecimento de javascript se alguem poder me ajudar vai me ajudar muito

contador_mapa.php

```
 $sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total1 FROM agenda_saidas where id_transfer1 = '1' ";
 $resultado1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die ("Erro na consulta1");
 $linha1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado1);
 $cancel_solicitado = $linha1['total1'];
```

Lista.php

```
 <div id="latestData"></div>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(function () {
 function getContadorMapa() {
    $.get("includes/principal/contador_mapa.php", function (result) {
        $('#latestData').html(result);
    });
  }

  getContadorMapa();
  setInterval(getContadorMapa, 20000);
  });

  </script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Basta usar o `play()`, nem precisa de JQuery, se usar o JQuery utilize o `.trigger('play')`.

Primeiro defina o audio que irá acionar:

```
<audio id="notificacao" preload="auto">
  <source src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2154&type=mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

> Este áudio é somente um exemplo, ele é do [SoundBible](http://soundbible.com/2154-Text-Message-Alert-1.html), criada por Daniel Simion, está sujeito a alguns termos de licença, [revise elas](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/br/) antes de utiliza-las, se assim desejar.

---

Depois basta que use:

```
$('#notificacao').trigger('play');
```

Se não, no *VanillaJS*:

```
document.getElementById('notificacao').play();
```

---

**Experimente:**

```js
let Contador = 1;

let ElemContador = document.querySelector("output[contador]");
let ElemAudio = document.querySelector("#notificacao");
let ElemBotao = document.querySelector("button[reproduzir]");

setInterval(function() {
  ElemContador.innerText = 10 - Contador;

  if (Contador === 10) {
    ElemAudio.play();
    Contador = 0;
  }

  Contador++;
}, 1000);

ElemBotao.addEventListener("click", function() {
  ElemAudio.load();
  ElemAudio.play();
})
```

```html
<p>É necessário que clique aqui para habilitar o Autoplay.</p>

<audio id="notificacao" preload="auto">
  <source src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2154&type=mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<output contador></output>

<p><button reproduzir>Dar Play</button></p>
```

*Caso esteja interessado em um exemplo COM JQuery, [veja a versão antiga desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/212415/2).*

Devido a limitações no browser, é preciso que interaja com a página para que o autoplay (e o play) funcionem. No caso do exemplo, é preciso que clique no quadrado do iframe do StackOverflow. Para mais informações sobre essa restrição acesse: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

Comment: Quase... mais eu queria quando chegasse um numero novo ai sim toque som

Comment: Basta que compare, `$('#latestData').html() != result){ // .play() //  }`, sem o HTML da página fica um tanto dificil saber como os elementos são inseridos, mas genericamente é isso.

Comment: Ressuscitando o post, estou tendo o mesmo problema do colega, porém gostaria que tocasse apenas 1 vez. Isso é possível?

Comment: @JM_2021 o `play.()` só executa uma única vez (talvez execute mais vezes se estiver com o atributo de `loop`).

Comment: @JM_2021 editei o exemplo para incluir um exemplo que o audio é acionado por botão, ou seja: uma única vez. Também reescrevi para remover o JQuery, uma vez que isso não é mais usado (como era em 2017).

Comment: Olá, Inkeliz. Certo. Acabei abrindo um novo post, pois vi que o meu problema era um pouco diferente do colega do post :)